# jQuery Code Style Guidelines

Tags: javascript, jquery

One of the jQuery Core Style Guidelines indicate:

> All RegExp operations should be done using .test() and .exec().
>   "string".match() is no longer used.

Why is `match()` not favoured?

Comment: Are you asking for the specific reason jQuery does not use it anymore, or in general why the other methods might be preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.exec` is simply a better version of `.match`

Let's see

```
var ret1 = string.match(regexp);
var ret2 = regexp.exec(string);
```

If regexp is a non global regular expression then the return values are the same.

However if regexp is a global regular expression (`/foo/g`) then match just returns an array of matches and that's it. No extra meta data like exec would return!

Comment: I thought the same. But even if no other data is needed in every case, striving for consistency (i.e. only using `exec`) could be another reason.